# Twilio IP messaging: Why am I getting error - WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state

Tags: twilio

I can't get why my browser console shows an error from time to time. As I can see this error doesn't break anything.

> media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/rtc/js/ip-messaging/releases/0.10.6/twilio-ip-messaging.js:22423
>   WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

Also I noticed that after some time of inactivity in chat window, I get 'messageAdded' event with a huge latency (it's take around 5+ seconds after message was sent), but Typing event works fine. Why is this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Closed socket errors indicate an issue with the local network and Chrome - can you confirm if you are going through a proxy? Could you also test using Firefox if possible?

If not, can you uncheck "automatically detect settings" in the network part of the Chrome Settings? Clear the cache and then update to the latest version and try again.

As far as the `messageAdded` event is concerned, what does your code look like?

Adding event listeners for [IP Messaging](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging):

```
 //set up listeners for events for the active channel
        activeChannel.on('messageAdded', addMessageToHistory);
```

And the `messageAdded` method I've seen used without issue:

```
function addMessageToHistory(message) {
    console.log('Message added, adding a message to the history, sid:' + message.sid);

    //get a handle to the chat history wrapper
    var $messageHistory = $('#chat-history');

    //process the message elements
    var $messageEntry = $('<div id="' + message.sid + '" class="chat-message clearfix"/>');
    var $messageContent = $('<div class="chat-message-content clearfix"/>');
    var $messageTime = $('<span id="time_' + message.sid + '" class="chat-time"/>').text(formatDate(message.timestamp));
    var $messageAuthor = $('<h5/>').text(message.author);
    var $messageBody = $('<p id="msgbody_" ' + message.sid + '" />').text(message.body);
    var $messageSeparator = $('<hr/>');

    //build the message content
    $messageTime.appendTo($messageContent);
    $messageAuthor.appendTo($messageContent);
    $messageBody.appendTo($messageContent);

    //build the message entry
    $messageContent.appendTo($messageEntry);
    $messageSeparator.appendTo($messageEntry);

    //ad the message entry to the history
    $messageEntry.appendTo($messageHistory);
    //scroll to end
    $messageHistory.scrollTop($('#chat-history')[0].scrollHeight);
    activeChannel.updateLastConsumedMessageIndex(message.index);
}
```

If your problem persists, then I'd suggest you [contact support](https://twilio.com/help/contact) where we can take a closer look.